# Can I build my homepage in squarespace and have custom code for rest of website on same domain

Tags: web-hosting, squarespace, velo

I build a website using PHP, HTML, Javascript, etc. However, I'd like to easily be able to edit the website and make it very appealing. I'd therefore love to build it with squarespace or wix. Is there a way of having the homepage of the domain be built with squarespace and all the other pages be custom code? Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If attempting to build both the "custom" pages (via PHP, HTML, and JS) within either platform *and* the platform's page-building tools, the answer is no, that is not possible.

From [Squarespace](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928-Adding-custom-code-to-your-site):

> Squarespace doesn’t support server-side code, including PHP, Ruby, Ruby on Rails, and SQL.

From [Wix](https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-using-php-programming-language):

> Wix Code, which uses Javascript, also allows the use of Java Script
> Libraries when using the HTML element. It is not possible to add PHP
> code to your Wix site.

It *is* possible to develop [static pages](https://developers.squarespace.com/static-pages/) on the Squarespace platform via Developer Mode, but this does not support PHP, only HTML, JSON-T, CSS, JS.

Other, theoretical workarounds could include the use of iframes, AJAX and or/proxy servers/services but may be prohibitively complex or not easy to maintain, or otherwise not well-behaved.